# Problem in using Sed to remove leading and trailing spaces

Tags: regex, sed

I am using the following code to remove both leading and tailing spaces from all lines of a file A.txt

```
sed 's/^[ \t]*//;s/[ \t]*$//' ./A.txt > ./B.txt
```

The problem occurs on the lines where there is a t in the beginning or at the end. So say for example, the original line that starts with the string "timezone" becomes "imezone"

Can you please tell me what is happening here? and also if there is a known solution to the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just try your code and it works like you expected. Not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 6):

Some older versions of sed don't understand C-style escape characters such as \t and treat that as two characters, '\' and 't'.  You can avoid the problem by using a literal tab character -- if you're typing this directly into the shell, type `Ctrl+V Tab`.

Comment: After some googling, I found that you can also use `Ctrl+v Ctrl+l` for tab. (work on Ubuntu atleast)

Comment: @NawaMan, are you sure that's not CTRL-v, CTRL-i ? CTRL-i is the tab character.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative, using whitespace character classes, if your variety of sed doesn't support `\s`:

```
sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//;s/[[:space:]]*$//'
```

Answer (score 2):

You might have better luck if you just use the whitespace character class:

```
sed -e 's/^\s*//' -e 's/\s*$//' A.txt > B.txt
```

Comment: Unfortunately if his sed is so old it doesn't understand \t, it probably doesn;t understand \s either.

Answer (score 2):

newer versions of sed understand \t but older versions may not have. You may be better off replacing \t with a literal tab (CTRL-V  will give you that)

What version of sed are you using on what system? (sed --version for GNU sed)

Answer (score 1):

gawk

```
awk '{gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"")}1' file
```